# Json List of Key:Value pairs with Spring

Tags: json, spring, jackson

What is Java equivalent of the following Json:

```
{
street: "New Ave",
someList : [{
code: "CO-DIRNET",
external : 800093078
  }]
}
```

I tried with:

```
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
  class Custom{
  private String street;
  private Some[] someList;

  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
  class Some{
    private String code;
    private String external;
  }
```

}

I also use:

```
ResponseEntity<Custom>response = restTemplate.getForEntity(json, Custom.class);
```

There are no errors but someList is null; I'm not sure if this is a valid Json.

Comment: Have you defined getters and setters?

Comment: Try using `List<Some> somelist` instead of `Some[]`

Comment: I have getters and setters and List doesn't work either

Comment: Add getters and setters for all the variebles

Answer (score 0):

use

`private List<Some> someList;`

instead of:

```
private Some[] someList;
```

And add getters & setters for all the variables in both the classes.